# Sending a list from JSP back to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am passing a list inside a session from servlet to a jsp as follows :

```
    HttpSession session = req.getSession();
session.setAttribute("list1", arrayList);
```

Inside the JSP I am printing the list as follows :

```
<form action="Save" method="post">
<c:forEach items="${list1}" var="item">
 ${item}<br>
 <c:set var="stringArray" value="${fn:split(item, ',')}" />
 <input type="text" name="Deivice" value="${stringArray[0]}" />
 <input type="text" name="DTA" value="${stringArray[1]}" />
 <input type="text" name="Type" value="${stringArray[2]}" />
 <br>
</c:forEach>
<input type="submit" value="Save">

</form>
```

Now I want to retrieve the list in a servlet (after the user modifies it in the UI)

How can I pass the values back to the servlet ? Basically, I want to pass a list,alow the user to modify the contents of the list on the UI and want the modified contents of the list in a servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply submit the form and get the values in Servelt using [request.getParameterMap()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29) or [request.getParameterValues(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29) that returns `String[]` for each parameter name that is submitted.

For e.g

```
String[] devices = request.getParameterValues("Deivice");
```